# Select children in XML where value is not equal to a value using XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

I am new to XML and xPath.
I have a XML structure similar to

```
<root>
  <child name="zero"/>
  <child name="one"/>
  <child name="two"/>
  <child name="three"/>
</root>
```

Is there a way to select only the children where name != "zero" using an xPath expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Just specify the condition in square brackets:

```
/root/child[not(@name="zero")]
```